# How to implement selection sort using forward iterators?

Tags: python

I'm working on a homework assignment where I shall implement selection sorting using forward iterators for both python lists and linked lists(single).

Here are some codes I have for iterators:

```
from abc import *

class ForwardIterator(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def getNext(self):
        return

    @abstractmethod
    def getItem(self):
        return

    @abstractmethod
    def getLoc(self):
        return

    @abstractmethod
    def clone(self):
        return

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.getLoc() == other.getLoc()

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not (self == other)

    def __next__(self):
        if self.getLoc() == None:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            item = self.getItem()
            self.getNext()
            return item

class ForwardAssignableIterator(ForwardIterator):
    @abstractmethod
    def setItem(self, item):
        """Sets the item at the current position."""
        return

class PythonListFAIterator(ForwardAssignableIterator):
    def __init__(self, lst, startIndex):
        self.lst = lst
        self.curIndex = startIndex

    def getNext(self):
        self.curIndex += 1

    def getItem(self):
        if self.curIndex < len(self.lst):
            return self.lst[self.curIndex]
        else:
            return None

    def setItem(self, item):
        if self.curIndex < len(self.lst):
            self.lst[self.curIndex] = item

    def getLoc(self):
        if self.curIndex < len(self.lst):
            return self.curIndex
        else:
            return None

    def clone(self):
        return PythonListFAIterator(self.lst, self.curIndex)
```

The `LinkedListFAIterator` is similar to `PythonListFAIterator`, plus `getStartIterator`, and `__iter__` method.

I don't know how I can write codes to implement selection sort with one paraemter, a FAIterator (the forward iterator). Please help me. I know I shall find the minimum element and put it at the beginning of the list. I also know that I shall use the clone method to create multiple iterators to keep track of multiple locations at once. But I don't know how to write the code.

Please give me some hints.

Comment: Have you tried [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) ?

Comment: Ya I tried. It only provides codes for the implementation using list indices rather than forward iterators. Thx for your reply though